# graph-js-sdk-web.js library not loading from CDN

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

`Microsoft Graph JavaScript` library stopped working some time ago (last weekend). 
I suppose that it is related to the release of the new `2.0.0` version of the library and switch to the new CDN: from `unpkg.com` to the `jsdelivr.net`.

We used the following URL to load the library in our project which worked find for us:

```
https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/graph-js-sdk-web.js
```

But now it redirects to a new URL which returns a `404`:

```
https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client@2.0.0/lib/graph-js-sdk-web.js
```

It is a breaking change for us and we need to release an updated version to fix the issue. And our customers will need to install an update. That's really bad.

We hope that someone from MS Office developers team will fix the redirection issue.

We expect that `https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/graph-js-sdk-web.js` will point to the most recent version in the 1.x branch.

We also posted an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/issues/224).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, `unpkg.com` was never an officially supported CDN (it was certainly not documented anywhere).

If you want to remain on v1.7 provided by unpkg, you can use this URI:

```
https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client@1.7.0/lib/graph-js-sdk-web.js
```

You can also get v1.7 from jsdelivr:

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client@1.7.0/lib/src/index.min.js
```

Comment: Thanks. We already did that (switched to the URI https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client@1.7.0/lib/graph-js-sdk-web.js) in new version of our software. 
Developers told me that unpkg.com was mentioned on official github repo, but i did not found it in the history of the repo. So, i suppose it is our mistake, that we used unpkg.com  in our project. 
We only thinked how we can resolve this issue for our custoemrs without upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

There was a rename of the package file during the 2.0 release.  It is now called `https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/graph-js-sdk.js`  We documented this in the release [blog post](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/microsoft-graph-sdk-for-javascript-2-0-0/) and in the [release notes](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/releases/tag/2.0.0).  Sorry for the inconvenience.